# How to Generate 10 random numbers form a range of 1 to 100?

Tags: javascript, loops, random, numbers

I am trying to use a loop from and Math.random to run Math.random 10 times in order to get 10 random numbers?

Comment: Duplicates or no? Okay: use a loop. Not okay: use a shuffle. Search, and play. Write code, and then (if needed) ask a question about the code and the behavior is does/doesn't exhibit.

Comment: A google search for "mdn random" gave me https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random, which offers all the examples you might want.

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  numbers.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
}
```

`Math.floor` makes the numbers into integers. Remove it if you're alright with decimal places.

Comment: The question asked for numbers from 1 to 100.

Comment: @torazaburo I forgot a 0 - fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you're producing 10 random integers and want them to range to up to 1000, you could do something like this:

```
var numberOfRandoms = 10;
var maxRange = 1000;
var results = [];

for (var i=0; i<numberOfRandoms; i++) {
    var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * maxRange) + 1);
    results.push(random);
}
```

You can play with the variables to work with different numbers of results or ranges.

Answer (score 0):

To get number between 1 to 100 use this

```
var numbers = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
 document.write(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
}
```

Explanation:

- 1 is your starting number
- 100 is your total possibilities

For more information, Click [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you have to ask yourself before wanting to generate 10 numbers between 1 ~ 100 is do you want to include 1 and not 100 or include 100 and not 1, or include 1 and 100.

```js
/*
  Including min num as a part of rand number
  Not including max num as a part of rand number
*/

function genRandNum(min, max) {
 return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
//this gives a float integer


/*
  Including min num as a part of rand number
  NOT including max num as a part of rand number
*/

function genRandNum(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}


/*
  Including min num as a part of rand number
  Including max num as a part of rand number
*/

function genRandNum(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

/*
  To generate 10 rand numbers
*/

function getRandNum() {
  var arr = [],
      len = 10;  
  for(var idx = 0; idx < len; idx++) {
    arr.push(genRandNum(1, 100));
  }
  return arr;
}

//To see the result
console.log(getRandNum());
```

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to figure out the same stuff, I'm using Swift 4; so this is what I came up with, a simple loop, the only thing I haven't still figure out is when it generates the same number 2 times ... but hope this helps:

```
// Generate 10 numbers in a range from 1 to  100    

for number in 1...10 {        
    print(arc4random_uniform(101)) 
}
```